# SHAP values from CARET

Tags: r, xgboost, r-caret, shap

I've been reading and having a go at creating some SHAP plots of some of my models but for the life of me can't find a package that integrates with `caret`.

I just need to sense check the direction of the features are sensible.

Let's say I build a simple `xgboost` model like so.

```
model_1 <- train(
  sales~., 
  data=example_df, 
  method="xgbTree", 
  preProcess=c('center', 'scale', 'zv'), 
  trControl=trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=5, repeats=2), 
  na.action = na.omit
)
```

I've done this a few times and done some feature engineering and selection but now want to see shap values. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput()`?

Answer (score 2):

The train object returned by `caret::train` contains an element `finalModel` which is of the type produced by the method.  In this case, it is an `xgboost` object.  You can use all the utilities within the `xgboost` package on this object.

To plot shap values, call `xgb.plot.shap(data = example_df, model = model_1$finalModel, top_n = 15)`.  To get the shap values themselves, you call the same function with `plot = FALSE` like this `shap_values <- xgb.plot.shap(data = example_df, model = model_1$finalModel, top_n = 15, plot = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks, knowing that will open a lot of doors. 

In terms of running the suggestion above I get the following error. 


`data: must be either matrix or dgCMatrix`


So I naturally wrapped the df in `as.matrix` but then get this:


`Error in xgb.DMatrix(newdata, missing = missing) : 
  'data' has class 'character' and length 35728.
  'data' accepts either a numeric matrix or a single filename.`



So from there I tried to apply some one-hot encoding with `dummyVars` assuming that would be the underlying method but the names don't match those in the model. Any tips for this?

Comment: Follow up that I have largely made it work like so.


  `df_dummy <- dummyVars('~.', data = example_df, sep ='') %>%
    predict(example_df) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%
    select(all_of(model_1$finalModel$feature_names)) %>%
    as.matrix()`

I'm sure there's a better way but at least I've got something

Comment: I think what's happening here is that caret creates a matrix input to xgboost itself internally.  You might want to make x matrix and y vector inputs to caret yourself with model.matrix(formula, data) so you can be sure that you're sending the same exact data to `train()` and `xgb.plot.shap()`.  In other words, call `train(x, y)` instead of `train(formula, data)`.

Comment: You will make you life much easier if you integer code the factors instead of dummy encoding.