# SHAP (Shapley Additive Explanations) with caret in R

Tags: r, caret, shap

I have used the caret R package to train a neural network, and a random forest. Can I find the SHAP values for feature importance in any way?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737056/shap-values-from-caret: what are the classes of the models that you get back?

Comment: Classification models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly modified from kernelshap's README: https://github.com/ModelOriented/kernelshap

```
library(caret)
library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)

fit <- train(
  Sepal.Length ~ . + Species * Sepal.Width, 
  data = iris, 
  method = "lm", 
  tuneGrid = data.frame(intercept = TRUE),
  trControl = trainControl(method = "none")
)

xvars <- colnames(iris[-1])
s <- kernelshap(fit, iris, predict, bg_X = iris, feature_names = xvars)
sv <- shapviz(s)
sv_importance(sv)
sv_dependence(sv, xvars)
```

[image]
[image]

### Remarks

1. Replace the linear model by anything else
2. If the dataset is larger than 500 obs, replace `bg_X` by a subsample of about 200--500 rows.
3. Probabilistic classification will work similarly

Comment: For the predict part of s because I have a classification problem I need: predict(model_glm, train, type = 'prob')$Yes. But I get the error;Error in kernelshap.default(model_glm, newtr, pred_fun = predict(model_glm,  : 
  is.function(pred_fun) is not TRUE. Can I fix that somehow?

Comment: `pred_fun = function(m, x) predict(m, x, type='prob')$Yes`  simply test with `pred_fun(data)`. If it is a numeric vector or matrix, you are safe.

Comment: Thanks! If the dataset is  larger than 500 obs what are the consequences? Because I would like to see the global feature importance.

Comment: A slow progress bar... You would usually subsample both X (explanation rows, 1000 rows) and bg_X (background data, 100 - 500 rows).

Comment: Last question: Can I visualize the interactions of variables?

Comment: Colors in dependence plots will give you hints about interactions. If you need SHAP interaction decompositions, then you can crunch them with treeshap (github project) for random forests, or easiest via XGBoost. I.e. outside caret. If you provide a specific example, it is easier.

Comment: How can I output the interaction plots? Because when I run the code the plot in Rstudio is very clustered.

Comment: I can only help if there is a self-contained example in the post.

Comment: It can work with the example you provided. How can I output the interaction plots in tiff or eps?

Comment: How can one cite the kernelshap package? Is there a doi?

Comment: citation("kernelshap") in R gives the bibtex :-)

Comment: Can I create a beesworm or a violin plot with the same package?

Comment: I'd suggest looking through "shapviz"'s Readme: `sv_importance(kind="bee)`

Comment: Done! Can I change the legend name? Instead of feature value to have variable value?

Comment: Feel free to do anything possible with ggplot. E.g. `+ labs(color="Variable value")`

Comment: Can I have a specific length in the x-axis? I.e -0. 5 to 0.5. From the documentation, I cannot find sth.

Comment: From "ggplot"s documentation, it should be rather clear: `+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-0.5, 0.5))`. I can recommend you Hadley's free book. It covers a lot of topics on ggplot: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/