# How to get SHAP values for caret models in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, shap, interpretation

I am trying to get SHAP values for my models (which I built using caret). I have an RF model, and the data is:

```
data = structure(list(Main_Street = structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("64", "70", "270"), class = "factor"), 
    Blocked_Lanes = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Total_Vehicle_Count = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L), Tractor_Trailer_Count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L), Weather_Winter_Storm = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), 
    Weather_Rain = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"), class = "factor"), Injuries_Count = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Accident_Overturned_Car = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("No", "Yes"
    ), class = "factor"), Fatalities_Count = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Speed = c(65L, 46L, 10L, 42L, 40L, 
    21L, 15L, 57L, 59L, 59L), Total_Volume = c(48.7, 22.5, 47.3, 
    102, 138, 75.3, 60.5, 83.3, 18, 26.7), Occupancy = c(3.5, 
    1.7, 40.8, 23.8, 14.1, 31, 27.1, 4.9, 2.6, 2.5), Lanes_Cleared_Duration = c(53L, 
    35L, 32L, 4L, 11L, 35L, 42L, 12L, 36L, 69L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The RF model is:

```
fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                           number = 10, 
                           repeats = 10) 

set.seed (2356)
randomforestGrid <-  expand.grid(mtry = c(2:sqrt(61))) # better be a dataframe
set.seed(2356)
rf_model <- train(Lanes_Cleared_Duration~.,
                 data = training, 
                 method = "rf", 
                 trControl = fitControl, 
                 metric= "RMSE",
                 verbose = FALSE, 
                 tuneGrid = randomforestGrid,
               n.trees = c(1:50)*100)
```

There are many sources on how to do SHAP plots, but none works for my data, and I keep getting errors. For example, [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737056/shap-values-from-caret) tried to ask a similar question, but it didn't solve the problem. Here is the plot that I want to get something similar to:
[image: SHAP Plot]

Is it also possible to export a data frame containing SHAP values for each variable?

Comment: Your code does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example slightly modified from our {kernelshap} [README](https://github.com/ModelOriented/kernelshap):

```r
library(caret)
library(kernelshap)
library(shapviz)

fit <- train(
  Sepal.Length ~ ., 
  data = iris, 
  method = "rf", 
  tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry = 2:4),
  trControl = trainControl(method = "oob")
)

# take subsample as bg_X if data has >500 rows or so
s <- kernelshap(fit, X = iris[, -1], bg_X = iris) 
sv <- shapviz(s)
sv_importance(sv, kind = "bee")
sv_dependence(sv, v = colnames(iris[, -1]))

head(s$S)
     Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width     Species
[1,]  0.18710551   -0.7689923 -0.11966640 -0.02138098
[2,] -0.04975942   -0.8421627 -0.16929579 -0.02247297
[3,] -0.05134404   -0.9807516 -0.21007903 -0.02603232
[4,] -0.01474815   -0.8314441 -0.18571834 -0.02234505
[5,]  0.16345002   -0.8066228 -0.13735372 -0.02104766
[6,]  0.27269103   -0.6231013 -0.06449333 -0.01560054
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: 1- Why do I get a list instead of a data frame containing each variable's SHAP values? 2- Why does the code take so long to run? 
3- An important note, When I installed the libraries, my R got damaged and the other libraries reported errors when they were called. I had to uninstall and install R and Rstudio to get the libraries working. 
Thanks for providing the code!

Comment: No idea what caused the problem. The SHAP values are stored as numeric matrix in a list that contains other stuff. There are many ways to make things faster, but that would require a working example from your side.